# How create JAR from upstream Web App as Dependency for downstream Web App

Tags: maven, netbeans, web-applications, netbeans-8

I have (amongst other modules) a NetBeans8.1 Maven web app project CoreWeb that (with other module dependencies resolved) runs standalone fine, and is supposed to under any circumstances at least build its default WAR and run standalone.

I have a 2nd NetBeans8.1 Maven web app project SpecWeb that depends on CoreWeb; it is to reuse both JSF managed beans from CoreWeb and also leverage XHTML composite component JSF resources from CoreWeb.

But on building SpecWeb it does not resolve the CoreWeb dependency, because CoreWeb does not (by default) **also** build a JAR:

```
Failed to execute goal on project SpecWeb: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project com.example.multi:SpecWeb:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
artifact com.example.multi:CoreWeb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

(I had this problem with an Ant version of my project with multiple modules and solved it using a small piece of Ant task script to build the extra JAR from CoreWeb for use in SpecWeb, worked perfectly.)

**Q: How can I generate a JAR (as well as the WAR) from CoreWeb for use in SpecWeb ?**

Under `Project > Actions: Build Project` I've tried adding various additional goals to `install` for the `Build Project` action (using the NetBeans prompting feature).

Using `install jar:jar` did not work. It indeed created a JAR (as well as the WAR), but that JAR only included the managed bean classes, not the resources, and on build from the "downstream" SpecWeb it still failed to find it:

```
$ jar tf target/CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/example/
com/example/multi/
.. Java managed bean classes ..

META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.example.multi/
META-INF/maven/com.example.multi/CoreWeb/
META-INF/maven/com.example.multi/CoreWeb/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.example.multi/CoreWeb/pom.properties
```

I get the same JAR structure built (without JSF XHTML composite component web resources) if I manually change the packaging in the pom.xml to `jar`:

```
<groupId>com.example.multi</groupId>
<artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<!--
<packaging>war</packaging>
-->
```

---

**EDIT: Overlays also not working (in NetBeans)**

I have also tried using [Overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), but it's not working as expected. As soon
as I turn the dependency into type `war` NetBeans can't resolve classes from CoreWeb imported into classes from SpecWeb, and it won't even compile (and the class files have NetBeans Java warnings because of the failed import):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
```

Also, as soon I enter `<type>war</type>` the CoreWeb project vanishes from the list under the project navigator node `SpecWeb > Dependencies`.

---

**Also tried [Warpath](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/usage.html) plugin**

NetBeans still does not see classes in CoreWeb imported into classes in SpecWeb, so SpecWeb won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research (mostly on the main Maven site) and trial and error, I have found a robust solution compatible with NetBeans.

A general description of the strategy. The trick is to create an additional "client" JAR version of the CoreWeb project for temporary use by the SpecWeb project (enabling NetBeans editor to "see" the classes of CoreWeb), and declare it as an additional dependency of only 'provided' scope (so it does not make it into the final SpecWeb WAR). Then also use [overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to combine both the composite components of CoreWeb and the managed beans of CoreWeb with the SpecWeb project into the final WAR, being careful to exclude the index.xhtml from CoreWeb.

**Steps**

In the pom.xml from CoreWeb include this:

```
        <!-- Also make JAR form using classifier during package phase -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>                
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

On build this will create:

```
 $ ls -1 CoreWeb/target/CoreW*
 CoreWeb/target/CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-client.jar
 CoreWeb/target/CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

 CoreWeb/target/CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT:
 META-INF/
 WEB-INF/
 index.xhtml
 resources/
```

(Note NetBeans can run CoreWeb independently directly over `CoreWeb/target/CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT` with its own `index.xhtml`.)

SpecWeb can then use CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-client.jar thus in its pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

   ...

    <!-- This is needed for the editor and for the compilation only (not at runtime) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>client</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- To prevent being written even to target folder -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- This is needed for the overlay -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note how there are 2 separate types of dependency of SpecWeb on CoreWeb:

- A dependency on the `CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-client.jar` using the classifier `client` and with scope `runtime` (so it won't be included under /target at all). *This will appear in the NetBeans project window under a special node **Non-Path Dependencies**, with a clear indication that it is for `[runtime]` only*.
- A dependency on the `CoreWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` for the overlay to use. This will appear in the NetBeans project window under the node **Dependencies**.

Then also in the pom.xml for SpecWeb specify the overlays (excluding the CoreWeb's index.html) and packaging (to be sure also [excluding](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) any "client" jars):

```
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*-client.jar</packagingExcludes>

                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>index.xhtml</exclude>
                        </excludes>                            
                    </overlay>
                    <overlay>
                        <!-- empty groupId/artifactId represents the current build -->
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The SpecWeb project behaves correctly in the NetBeans editor (classes from CoreWeb are seen), compiles ok, and can be run over `SpecWeb/target/SpecWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT` with its own `index.html`, with access to both the JSF managed beans and JSF composite components of CoreWeb.

*CAVEAT: NetBeans XHTML editor will complain when editing JSF pages from SpecWeb that the composite components provided by CoreWeb don't exist because of this known [NetBeans Bug 257684 - JSF 2 composite components in JAR are not recognized](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257684) , but the project will still run ok.*